# Jsch, execute commands over JumpHosts

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

Help Jsch, execute commands over JumpHosts: i need to get SSH access in a server which i can't reach directly, because there's a SSH jump server in middle. I use JSCH library, but documentation (JumpHosts.java example) is about how to get the server file directory. Any suggestions please

```
  public static void main(String[] arg){


try{
  JSch jsch=new JSch();

  String host="host ip";
  if(arg.length>0){
    host=arg[0];
  }

  String user = "username"; 


  session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
  String passwd = "password";
  session.setPassword(passwd);

  UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo(){
    public void showMessage(String message){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
    }


  };

  session.setUserInfo(ui);
  session.connect(30000);   // making a connection with timeout.

  channel=session.openChannel("shell");
  channel.setInputStream(System.in);
  channel.setOutputStream(System.out);

  channel.connect(3*1000);



}
catch(Exception e){
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to the server using a normal ssh client (like putty or openssh)?

Comment: Maybe try [using something like this](https://blog.gordonturner.com/2017/04/09/creating-a-ssh-tunnel-in-java/)?

Comment: Yes and i can jump to the second host using a typical ssh client. Problem comes from Java app: i can connect from app and get promp from server1 (jump server), but i don´t know how to connect or execute commands on second server

Comment: Matt Clark: Thanks i'm gonna try it

Comment: How do you do it when using an SSH client?  What's stopping you from doing exactly the same thing using JSCH?

Answer (score 0):

I just did what i asked. I share for anyone who need it: After this, you have to create Channel("Shell/Exec") and manage streams in/out (and sorry about my english)

```
public static void sesionA(){
     try {
        Session sessionA = jSch.getSession(username, hostA);  
        Properties config = new Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        sessionA.setConfig(config);
        sessionA.setPassword(passwordA);
        sessionA.connect();


        if(sessionA.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Connected host A!");
            forwardedPort = 2222;
            sessionA.setPortForwardingL(forwardedPort, hostB, 22);      
        }

    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

 public static void sesionB(){


        try {
            Session sessionB = jSch.getSession(username, "localhost", forwardedPort);

        Properties config = new Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        sessionB.setConfig(config);
        sessionB.setPassword(passwordB);
            sessionB.connect();

          if(sessionB.isConnected()) {
             System.out.println("Connected host B!");
              }
     }

 }
```